# Python NameError - Name not defined after User Input

Tags: python, input

All,

I have the following code:

```
val1 = str(input("Enter string element 1/3: "))
val2 = int(input("Enter integer element 2/3: "))
val3 = float(input("Enter float element 3/3: "))

lst = [val1, val2, val3]
tpl = (val1, val2, val3)
dict = {"First element: ":val1, "Second element: ":val2, "Third element: ":val3}

print("/n")
print("Here is your list: ", lst)
print("Here is your tuple: ", tpl)
print("Here is your dictionary ", dict)

print("/n")
val4 = input("Add a new str list element: ")
lst.append(val4)
print("Here is your new list ", lst)
```

But i seem to get this return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Test2", line 1, in <module>
    val1 = str(input("Enter string element 1/3: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

However, int and float both work - so why doesn't string? It's saying that 'test' isn't defined, but i thought it because defined after the user inputted the word?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: `"/n"` is not a newline; `"\n"` is.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `raw_input` instead of `input` in Python 2.

```
>>> float(input(": "))
: test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

vs

```
>>> float(raw_input(": "))
: test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): test
```

`input` evaluates its input as an expression, so if you enter `test` at its prompt, it tries to evaluate that as a name.

`raw_input` always returns the string you type as a `str` object, so you still need to take care that what you type is a value input for whatever you intend to pass it to.